# Sense of options = merge({}, options) statement

Tags: javascript, node.js

In the source code of [serve-static](https://github.com/expressjs/serve-static) npm library I have seen the following line

```
 options = merge({}, options)
```

where `merge` function is from [utils-merge](https://github.com/jaredhanson/utils-merge) library and it has exactly the following body

```
exports = module.exports = function(a, b){
  if (a && b) {
    for (var key in b) {
      a[key] = b[key];
    }
  }
  return a;
};
```

What is the sense of `options = merge({}, options)` statement since it just joins `options` object with an empty object?

Comment: It initializes `options` to an empty object if `options` is `undefined`or leaves `options` with the same values if it's already there (effectively making a shallow copy, as pointed out by Sirko).

Comment: Actually it makes a shallow copy of `options`.

Comment: Similarly, you will see the `$.extend()` function doing the same thing in nearly all jQuery plugins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the sense of `options = merge({}, options)` statement since it just joins `options` object with an empty object?

To do exactly that. It copies all properties into a new object, where they cannot be modified anymore even if the caller of `serveStatic` still holds a reference to the `options` object he passed.

However, avoiding that the caller messes with the object is not the only reason for detaching it. If we read on, we see things like

```
delete options.setHeaders
options.maxage = options.maxage || options.maxAge || 0
options.root = root
```

so we also want to avoid messing with the object that was passed to us. Mutating your arguments is an antipattern.

Answer (score 1):

`merge({}, options)` creates the new object which has the same attributes as source object (so it is the simplest way to clone JS object). But if you don't pass an empty object as the destination object to merge function or just skip this line, all changes on `options` object inside `serveStatic()` function will affect external object what passed to function `serveStatic()`.

Here is the detailed explanation of this nuance of JavaScript language: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3638034/1806421